# Good free lib for compression

Tags: c++, compression

I need compress library for following needs:

1) Packing directory in one file with extension of my choice ( .pack for example )

2) Work with content in this file (directory) without unpaking it

3) Mechanism for encrypting

I already know about zlib, but for me it is ugly documented and not written anywhere what features are support from it

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Comment: zlib is used by almost every program everywhere. why can't you use it?

Comment: `zlib` is fast but compression is not as good as that of `bzip2` and `xz`.

Comment: `zlib` is not "ugly documented" - it's probably THE most documented compression library.

Comment: I don't say that zlib is not documented.
I say that zlib is ugly documented for me.
I don't want to read documentation with this style.
Next time read carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Packing directory in one file with extension of my choice ( .pack for example )

Most archivers don't require you to use a particular file extension. Regardless, one can still invoke `file` on a file to guess its content type.

> Work with content in this file (directory) without unpaking it

It's possible to create a file list manually and prepend any archive file with that. Often, `.sh` installers for Linux contain a shell script in the beginning, followed by some magic line like `__ARCHIVE_START__` followed by a binary archive. Hence it is possible to read lines from a file until `__ARCHIVE_START__` line has been read. The rest of the file is an archive file.

> Mechanism for encrypting

One easy way is to use different libraries for archiving and encrypting:

1. Bundle the files into one `.tar`.
2. Archive `.tar` into say `.tar.xz`.
3. Prepend the `.tar.xz` with file list followed by `__ARCHIVE_START__` line.
4. Encrypt the file with any encryption library you please.

Comment: Thanks your answer is useful for me

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not a compression library.  You want a compression, archiving, and encryption library or libraries.  You need archiving to put a directory of files into a single file.

You can use zlib to do the compress part, but not archive or encrypt.  [zlib](http://zlib.net/) is documented in [zlib.h](http://zlib.net/manual.html) and you can see a [usage example there](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html), as well as many examples in the [source distribution package](http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.7.tar.gz).

You can construct your own archiving format, or you can use existing ones for which there are libraries such as [zip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/) or [tar](http://www.feep.net/libtar/), both of which use or can be directed to use zlib.

You can use [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) for strong encryption.

Comment: Thanks your answer is useful for me